# tag-it- autofocus does not allow to type in shorter autocomplete word

Tags: jquery, autofocus, tag-it

I am using tag-it with availableTags

```
$('#taglabel').tagit({
  autocomplete: { autoFocus :true},
  availableTags: ['this','that','label1']
});
```

The problem is when i type in input box, it shows me avilable list with first item selected, which is good. But i cannot type th, or tha i.e, it autoselect this and that.